# Is there a way to get device (ios simulator) health stats in Detox react Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator, detox, applesimutils

I have been writing functional tests using detox to test a react native app. And while doing so, I have observed my functional test fails due to the simulator getting stuck/froze.
Hence I was trying to kill the device (simulator) whenever the simulator freezes.
But to implement the same, we would need to know the device's health status. Is there a way wherein I can identify the device health stats?

Answer (score 0):

If your app hangs and/or your test is stuck, you can follow [the guide](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.Synchronization.md#identifying-which-synchronization-mechanism-causes-us-to-wait-too-much) to see what is hanging the task/app.

If the simulator runtime itself is buggy and hangs, there is no API that Apple provides for testing how buggy their stuff is. Open a bug report with Apple and make sure you are using the latest Xcode available.